# Возможно ли такое в Mysql

Tags: mysql

Чтобы вывести тривиально записи упорядоченно по алфавиту, но чтобы первой была запись с ID = 2
Вот так:

```
2 - Россия
1 - Албания
3 - Афганистан
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER BY FIELD(id, 2)`таким занимается, насколько знаю

Comment: Работает. только уже срабатывает не по алфавиту

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk `ORDER BY FIELD(id, 2), title DESC`?

Answer (score 2):

В качестве примера, которое будет работать не только на `MySQL`:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
   ,name
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо вывести сначала запись с id=2, а потом все оставшиеся записи, упорядоченные по алфавиту, так?
Тогда только через UNION